# Ace Editor remove my HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, ace-editor

Here's my html:

```
...<div class="myclass"><label>Default</label></div>
```

my javascript:

```
ace.edit(el); // where el is the dom element div.myclass shown above
```

The editor is rendered properly!

The editor only comes up with "Default". No html to edit.

When I look at the code in debug mode on chrome, I see that the edit function retrieve the value of my element using (line 18474):

```
value = dom.getInnerText(el);
```

Which in turn result in:

```
return el.textContent;
```

then el innerHTML is blanked using (18475):

```
el.innerHTML = '';
```

This seems very strange to me. el.innerHTML correctly displays

```
"<label>Default</label>"
```

Is it me or there's something wrong?

How can I edit the html content of a div using Ace editor if this is normal behavior? What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer here
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/519

I'll try it and let you guys know if this doesn't solve it

You basically need to

el = document.getElementById("editor"); text = el.innerHTML editor = ace.edit(el) editor.session.setValue(text)

Answer (score 0):

Ace uses textContent instead of innerHTML because it's not possible to pass arbitrary text using innerHTML. E.g if you have `'<div class="myclass">'` innerHTML will make it `'<div class="myclass"></div>'` and `<script>alert('haha')</script>` will display alert dialog.
You can use textarea or xmp tag, to not make browser parse the text but there again you need to escape `</textarea`. So the sanest way is to escape special html characters like < and & and use textContent.

Answer (score 0):

If your code content has HTML use `textarea` as the container to call on `Ace Editor`

> **Atention**
> On `C#` and `Javascript` use `innerText` a not `~~innerHtml~~`.

Example

**HTML**

```html
<textarea id="aceeditorcontent" runat="server" clientidmode="Static"></textarea>

<script>
var aceeditor = ace.edit("aceeditorcontent", {
        theme: "ace/theme/chrome",
        mode: "ace/mode/html_ruby",
        maxLines: Infinity,
        showPrintMargin: false,
        wrap: true,
        autoScrollEditorIntoView: true,
        enableSnippets:true
    });
</script>
```

**Csharp**

```cs
aceeditorcontent.InnerText = "<html>......</html>";
```

**javascript**

```js
document.getElementById("aceeditorcontent").innerText = "<html>......</html>";
```